# PHP : I can't echo spaces into a class name

Tags: php, html, echo

Sparing comments about the intelligence of my approach, can you help with this issue?

I have a `<div>`, the contents of which I'm styling differently depending on whether it has the simple class name "topic" or both "topic" and "focused". I'm using simple logical test to determine whether it's focused, then echoing the class name into the html. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php $topic__class = "topic". ( is_focused($var) ? "  focused" : "" ); ?>  
<div class=<?php echo $topic__class; ?> >  
<div class="next class">
```

etc. The results in browser (Chrome element inspector):

```
<div class="topic"  focused>  
<div class="next class">
```

Not at all what I need. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
For what it's worth, it's not the `is_focused()` function - i can replace that with `1==1` or `true` and it doesn't parse.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Ehm, what is the question? Where is your php code?

Comment: So it will either be `topic` or `topicfocused`?

Comment: So what trouble are you having outputting the classes? Show the code where you attempted it and describe whats happening

Comment: Post your code, `<div class="topic focused">` should work fine and PHP will echo that no problem

Comment: Sorry, I submitted it before I'd typed the question out. Fumble fingers....

Comment: Also, why so many downvotes on this question?

Comment: I think the downvotes were mostly people being over-hasty judging the incomplete question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- div class=<?php echo $topic__class; ?> >
+ div class="<?php echo $topic__class; ?>">
```

Comment: That works according to Chrome's element inspector; however, when I view source, it shows it as `<div class="topic&nbsp;&nbsp;focused" >
` which breaks my ability to parse it as separate class names.

Comment: @somewhatsapient do you run your code through anything that would convert whitespace to `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Only my stupidity. During many tests to figure this out, I'd left a version of the variable with `&nbsp;` incorporated. Weeding that out and doing it properly from the beginning fixed it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put quotes around the HTML attribute. At the moment, it will read as an attribute `class=topic`, and a separate attribute `focussed` (after the space).

Instead of `<div class=<?php echo $topic__class; ?> >` use `<div class="<?php echo $topic__class; ?>" >`